# Access image from Web API Core Folder from Browser

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How can access image from folder from web api core? I am doing as below

```
https://localhost:44344/Uploaded_Documents/IMG_20190314_205925_3be1d2b3-3bac-4184-8468-995d58d5ff80.jpg
```

But it is giving below error.

[image]

Me configuration is like below.

[image]

Image path is like below.
[image]

How can I access this image from browser in web api core ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you would like to access your file out of `wwwroot` folder,you need to configure the Static File Middleware as follows:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();// For the wwwroot folder

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uplodaed_Documents")),
            RequestPath = "/Uplodaed_Documents"
        });
//Enable directory browsing
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Uplodaed_Documents")),
            RequestPath = "/Uplodaed_Documents"
        });

app.UseMvc();
```

You could refer to asp.net core static files [Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: wwwroot in API project?